# Flutter default splash view fading animation

Tags: android, flutter

Flutter makes it possible to add your logo in a view at app start to avoid blank cold start screen, i have made an initial route with the same image centered so that the transition be seamless,there is however a fade animation from that screen to the first Flutter route, how can we disable that animation ?

Answer (score 0):

I think for now there isn't any solution from the team to this. [Here is some workaround for Android.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63156) I haven't tried it.

[Here is an open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63156) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37818) although that second one proposes some workaround for iOS when you disable that fade effect it causes to crash.